# Second .exe file is not included in ClickOnce publish

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

The application I'm working is compiled into 2 executables that need to be included in the publish. Despite having both of them set as required in the settings, the [Name].Launcher.exe is missing. Why is that?
[image: Publish settings]
[image: ClickOnce directory]

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't deleted by antivirus software?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT there was no such notification during publish + the second .exe file is present when building normally